# R pivot_longer and ggplot errorbar with two name/key columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyr, errorbar

Let's assume we have the following artifical data:

```
  df <- data.frame(Year = c(2015,2016,2017,2018),
               GPP_mean = c(1700,1800,1750,1850),
               Reco_mean = c(-1700,-1800,-1750,-1850),
               GPP_min = c(1600,1700,1650,1750),
               GPP_max = c(1800,1900,1850,1950),
               Reco_min = c(-1600,-1700,-1650,-1750),
               Reco_max = c(-1800,-1900,-1850,-1950))
```

I'd like to plot bars for each mean value and use the min/max columns for the errorbar. 
This is what I've achieved so far:

```
df %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -Year,
                 names_to = c("variable", "stats"),
                 names_sep = "_")
```

Which gives us:

```
    # A tibble: 24 x 4
    Year variable stats value
   <dbl> <chr>    <chr> <dbl>
 1  2015 GPP      mean   1700
 2  2015 Reco     mean  -1700
 3  2015 GPP      min    1600
 4  2015 GPP      max    1800
 5  2015 Reco     min   -1600
 6  2015 Reco     max   -1800
 7  2016 GPP      mean   1800
 8  2016 Reco     mean  -1800
 9  2016 GPP      min    1700
10  2016 GPP      max    1900
# … with 14 more rows
```

So far, so good (I guess?).
From here on, I have no clue of how I can tell ggplot to plot the mean values as the bars and use min/max for the errorbars. Any help appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

additional solution using `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- df %>% 
  pivot_longer(-Year, names_sep = "_", names_to = c("index", ".value"))

ggplot(out, aes(Year, mean, fill = index)) +
  geom_col() +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = min, ymax = max), width = 0.5)
```

Answer (score 1):

You should stick with your original data frame. There's no need to pivot longer for this:

```r
  ggplot(df, aes(Year, GPP_mean)) + 
    geom_col(fill = "forestgreen", colour = "black") + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = GPP_min, ymax = GPP_max), width = 0.5) +
    geom_col(aes(y = Reco_mean), fill = "red", colour = "black", position = "dodge") + 
    geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = Reco_max, ymax = Reco_min), width = 0.5)
```

[image]

Comment: I avoided gather/pivot_longer for some time and now I am trying to get used to it, as I think this is how the tidyverse is meant to be used. But it seems like that there are situations where a "tidy" data.frame does more harm than good. I am still wondering if it were possible to plot the data the way I approached it, but anyways thank you for the answer.

Comment: @FelixPhl I would still count this as tidy data. You have 6 variables per observation, and 4 unique observations (years). Pivoting longer is a powerful tool, and I use it a lot, but tools only exist to help us achieve an end product. If you find that you are using a particular tool just because "that's what you're supposed to do", when there is absolutely no benefit to doing so for you or anyone else, you are entering the realm of [Cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming)